# How to whitelist / blacklist facebook api user signups?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using Facebook login for my website and I'd like to be able to whilelist / blacklist users when they sign up.

That is, I'm imagining having a list of users that have been invited to user the platform and a list of users that are banned from the platform. Is there a way of going this?

I noticed there's a roles tab in my FB App so I can assign testers. I suppose this is a workaround, but I dont think this will work once I submit my app as live.

Answer (score 1):

With the App Scoped IDs, the only way i can think of is to let them authorized your App, put them in a waiting list and approve/deny them in an admin interface. You only know the user ID AFTER authorization.

Comment: yeah. I was afraid of this. bummer